# "ztemtvcdromd: no process found" when removing crossplatformui

Tags: dpkg

When I am doing `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install` (any software) then this is showing in terminal

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 146237 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get -f install`? If that does not work, add the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm` to the question.

Comment: Not Working. Same error :(

Comment: Please add the contents of the file (of the previous comment) to the question.

Comment: Sorry but I cant understand your word. May be for being poor in english :(

I did every thing written in first comment now what to do? 
I am in big problem cause I can't install any software for this reason :(

Comment: I said open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm` and add its contents to the question. To open the file, run the command `gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm`.

Comment: @ekaki.sam how did you solve this issue. I am facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove that package it's looking for a process called `ztemtvcdromd` as part of the `postrm` scripts, and since it doesn't find it it fails. This is a bug of the maintainer of the package which should have used `|| exit 0` so the process never returns different code of 0.

To fix this you need to edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm` and modify the line `sudo killall -p ztemtvcdromd` to `sudo killall -p ztemtvcdromd || exit 0`, then you can remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple as suggested by @Braiam.

Just open the file crossplatformui.postrm with administrative privilege . Type in terminal

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm
```

Type your root password and enter.

Find the line `sudo killall -9 ztemtvcdromd` .Now replace it with `sudo killall -9 ztemtvcdromd || exit 0`. ( In my case it is 9 ztemtvcdromd,in your case it may vary like " p ztemtvcdromd ". Then modify accordingly. Now save the file and close it. Done!

Go to synaptic manager, search for crossplatformui, check for complete removal, then apply! That is all crossplatformui will be removed completely!

Answer (score -3):

the best to fix this is removing the files of crossplatformui from /var/dpkg/info directory

```
cd /var/dpkg/info
ls | grep crossplatformui
```

output is similar :

```
crossplatformui.conffiles
crossplatformui.list
crossplatformui.md5sums
crossplatformui.postinst
crossplatformui.postrm
```

remove all the files

```
sudo rm crossplatformui.*
```

check if there is package by name of crossplatformui

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq crossplatformui
```

issue the command to unstuck the package to be installed
   -f is for fixing

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Cheers 
Acutal source : http://shekher-techprobs.blogspot.in/2012/03/removing-crossplatformui-ztemtvcdromd.html

Comment: before downvoting , pass a comment please  . If something is wrong it can be improved .